# Adding for loops to dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, python-2.7

I'm having trouble inserting for loop answers into list:

```
 for i in word_list:
        if i in word_dict:
            word_dict[i] +=1
        else:
            word_dict[i] = 1
print word_dict
```

with this i get dictionaries of word counts like

```
{'red':4,'blue':3}
{'yellow':2,'white':1}
```

is it possible to somehow add these answers to a list like

```
 [{'red':4,'blue':3},{'yellow':2,'white':1}]
```

basically i get 5 dictionaries from a for loop, is it possible to put all those dictionaries into one list, without changing each dictionary. Every time i try to put them into one list it just gives me something like:

```
[{{'red':4,'blue':3}]
[{'yellow':2,'white':1}]
[{etc.}]
```

http://pastebin.com/60rvcYhb

this is the copy of my program, without the text files im using to code with, basically books.txt just contains 5 different txt files from 5 authors, and im at the point where i have the word counts of all of them in seperate dictionaries which i want to add to one list like:

```
 [{'red':4,'blue':3},{'yellow':2,'white':1}]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
word_dict_list = []

for word_list in word_lists:
    word_dict = {}
    for i in word_list:
        if i in word_dict:
            word_dict[i] +=1
        else:
            word_dict[i] = 1
    word_dict_list.append(word_dict)
```

or simply:

```
from collections import Counter
word_dict_list = [ dict(Counter(word_list)) for word_list in word_lists]
```

example:

```
from collections import Counter
word_lists = [['red', 'red', 'blue'], ['yellow', 'yellow', 'white']]
word_dict_list = [ dict(Counter(word_list)) for word_list in word_lists]
# word_dict_list == [{'blue': 1, 'red': 2}, {'white': 1, 'yellow': 2}]
```

Comment: +1 Although you should leave them as `Counter`. I don't see the need to convert them back.

Comment: See the problem with mine is that my actual word counts are paragraphs and when i do the first test it puts each dictionary into their own lists like:[{'red':3,'blue:2}] [{'yellow':4,'white':5}]

Comment: @DylanWard - it would be helpful to put this information into the question.

Comment: well i get my for loop answers in like 5 separate dictionaries. is it possible to take all those dictionaries and put it into one list, with each dictionary still its own?